# Flushing Nginx DNS cache while using upstream load balancing

Tags: nginx

I've recently encountered an issue where due to the DNS cache within Nginx a service was negatively impacted because we use `upstream` settings within the associated Nginx configuration. I've reviewed the following issue already as well as searching for a solution, none of them use `upstream`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956979/error-with-ip-and-nginx-as-reverse-proxy . Due to the fact we use an AWS ELB we identify two of the same server values that sit inside the upstream. The relevant section looks like this:

```
upstream my_server {
  server blah.domain.com:443;
  server blah.domain.com:443;
}

server {

  listen 1024;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/my-access-log.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/my-error-log.log;

  keepalive_timeout 5;
  client_max_body_size 40M;

  location /blah {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host blah.domain.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://my_server;
}
```

So I know that I could use a resolver and create an http section which the server section sits inside of, however I can't set a variable that will then use the Nginx load balancer functionality. I can't set a variable inside of upstream as it is not supported (which would force the DNS cache to refresh as noted here: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832).

So my question is how do I work around this? How do I maintain the functionality that `upstream` provides for load balancing while also ensuring the DNS cache is flushed without restarting the service in the community version of Nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality described is provided in NGINX Plus, the complete application delivery platform that provides additional features.

You can read about the "[On-the-Fly Reconfiguration](https://www.nginx.com/products/on-the-fly-reconfiguration/)" functionality provided by NGINX Plus and see the documentation under the ["Dynamically Configurable Group"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#example) section for more information about this specific feature.

*(Disclaimer: I am affiliated with NGINX, Inc - the company that develops both versions of NGINX).*

Comment: Hey Patrick, I probably should have specific this in my question original (which I have now edited for clarity) but is there any way to do this with the community version? The commercial version isn't in the cards currently. Thank you for your answer regardless.

Comment: Our site rules require you to disclose your affiliation when promoting a commercial product.

Comment: @womble Thanks for the info, but I didn't think it applies to this question after reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204665/do-i-need-to-disclose-my-affiliation-on-a-non-promotional-technical-answers-on. Please clarify?

Comment: @Forrest Dynamically configurable upstream groups are only available in the specified version of NGINX. There may be third party solutions (I'm not familiar with any).

Comment: @PatrickNommensen that was a question about an open source project, and, as the question-asker has clarified, they did not ask about your product, so you're "taking [an] opportunity to suggest [your] project as a solution", rather than answering a question asked specifically about your product.  You're also not (clearly) indicating your affiliation in your profile, which the question you linked to recommended.

Comment: @womble Yes, the original question has been clarified to suggest which version of NGINX -- we have an open source and commercial product. Forrest reached out via Twitter, and you're correct, I haven't had a chance to submit profile information. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @PatrickNommensen Alright thanks for the answer, I'll wait a few days and if no one provides a better solution for the community edition I'll mark this as correct and see about opening an issue to get variable declaration in the upstream section

Comment: @PatrickNommensen, please edit your answer to clarify your affiliation with the commercial product you are promoting.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer. While it does not address the issue directly, it does not seem as though there is a way to do this currently with the community edition of Nginx so this is the only option.